# How \hbadness and \hfuzz influence "Overfull \hbox" warning?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

TeXbook (p.302) says:

> A nonempty hbox is considered “overfull” if its glue cannot shrink to achieve
>   the specified size, provided that \hbadness is less than 100 or that the excess
>   width (after shrinking by the maximum amount) is more than \hfuzz. It is “tight” if
>   its glue shrinks and the badness exceeds \hbadness; it is “loose” if its glue stretches
>   and the badness exceeds \hbadness but is not greater than 100; it is “underfull” if
>   its glue stretches and the badness is greater than \hbadness and greater than 100.

I have a question about case 1. Let's consider it, using the following template:

```
\hbadness=-1 % to report the badness
\spaceskip.3333em \rightskip0pt plus20pt % allow only 20pt of stretchability
\def\text{The badness of this line is 1000.}
\setbox0=\hbox{\text}
\hsize=\wd0 \advance\hsize by Xpt \noindent\text\break
\end
```

1)

> A nonempty hbox is considered “overfull” if its glue cannot shrink to achieve the specified size ⟨quote omitted⟩ ... TeX prints a warning message and displays
>   the offending box, whenever such anomalies are discovered.

In the template substitute `Xpt` with `-0.1pt` and we confirm statement (1):

```
Overfull \hbox (0.1pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\tenrm The bad-ness of this line is 1000.
```

But I do not understand what the following phrase (which is marked as "⟨quote omitted⟩" above) means:

> provided that \hbadness is less than 100 or that the excess width (after shrinking by the maximum amount) is more than \hfuzz

because "`Overfull \hbox`" message is always printed.

---

*this not part of the question - it is just a notice: the following cases are considered using the same timplate*

2)

> It is “tight” if its glue shrinks and the badness exceeds \hbadness ... TeX prints a warning message and displays the offending box, whenever such anomalies are discovered.

In the template change `plus` to `minus` and `Xpt` to `-10pt` and we confirm statement (2):

```
Tight \hbox (badness 12) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\tenrm The bad-ness of this line is 1000.
```

3)

> it is “loose” if its glue stretches and the badness exceeds \hbadness but is not greater than 100... TeX prints a warning message and displays the offending box, whenever such anomalies are discovered.

We confirm this by substituting `0.1pt` and `20pt` instead of `Xpt` in the template:

```
Loose \hbox (badness 0) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\tenrm The bad-ness of this line is 1000.
```

```
Loose \hbox (badness 100) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\tenrm The bad-ness of this line is 1000.
```

4)

> it is “underfull” if its glue stretches and the badness is greater than \hbadness and greater than 100... TeX prints a warning message and displays the offending box, whenever such anomalies are discovered.

This is confirmed using `20.1pt` instead of `Xpt`:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 101) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\tenrm The bad-ness of this line is 1000.
```

Comment: If I run your first example (with `Xpt` replaced by `-.1pt`) and set `\hbadness` to at least `100`, I get exactly the described behaviour: The "Overfull \hbox" warning disappears.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger yes but just set `\hfuzz` to 2pt, why doesn't that suppress the overfull message, that's the question I think (semantics of "or" in English is confusing at the best of times:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the sentence 50 times then

> provided that `\hbadness` is less than 100 or that the excess width (after shrinking by the maximum amount) is more than `\hfuzz`.

Means that if (as here) you set `\hbadness` to be less than 100, then any overfull  box will be reported, and `\hfuzz` has no effect.

Given how often I have read that paragraph in the TeXBook I can't say I ever read it that way until you provided this example.  If you had asked, I'd have said that setting `\hfuzz` to a non zero value inhibits warnings about boxes that are overfull by a smaller amount without considering this extra condition on `\hbadness`, so nice example:-)

Comment: DEK should have printed pseudo code instead of that paragraph.

Comment: @Skillmon that's what `tex.web` is for....